# Costume world fail to load in Hector_quadrotor_gazeboo

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there.
I am trying to load a costume world for Hector_quadrotor_gazebo using the same procedure i have done with turtlebot_gazebo that is:
i run :

```
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world.launch
```

then edited the empty world and 'save the world as' 2.world.
nest step i ran this command:

```
~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world.launch world_file:=/home/mastlab/2.world
```

and it ignored the edited world and loaded the original empty_world.
next thing i tried was to modify the (2) into the following:

```
~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world.launch world:=/home/mastlab/2.world
```

and nothing change.

i think the problem is i dont know what is the default world for hector_quadrotor_gazebo because it was pretty straight forward with turtlebot_gazebo .( `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`) .
i am running ROS Kinetic and Gazebo 7. also I am quiet new to ROS and Gazebo.

Anyone have any idea?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287221/costume-world-fail-to-load-in-hector_quadrotor_gazeboo/) by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved, by adding the line `<arg name="world_name" value="/home/mastlab/2.world"/>` to the launch file so it will be :

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
<arg name="world_name" value="/home/mastlab/2.world"/>
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) with karma: 26 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the [source for the `quadrotor_empty_world.launch`](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/blob/kinetic-devel/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/launch/quadrotor_empty_world.launch) you'll see that it doesn't have a `world` argument.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find hector_quadrotor_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor.launch" />
</launch>
```

So, what you'll want to do is create a new launch file in your package that's similar to the one that you're using and include your custom world instead. You can make it a little more flexible by add a `world` argument that you're trying to use (let's call it `world_name` to be consistent with [the `empty_world.launch` file](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/launch/empty_world.launch)):

```
<launch>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" default="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" default="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="world_name"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_name)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find hector_quadrotor_gazebo)/launch/spawn_quadrotor.launch" />
</launch>
```

Now, you should be able use it similarly to how you're currently trying to use it:

```
roslaunch my_package my_world.launch world_name:=2.world
```

One caveat is indicted in the `empty_world.launch` file

> the `world_name` is with respect to `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` environmental variable

so you might have to work that out. Hopefully, this at least gives you something to go off of.

---

**Update:**

From the [Gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components),

> `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`: colon-separated set of directories where Gazebo will search for other resources such as world and media files.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
thanks alot @jayess . i have created new launch file named it empty_world_costume.launch that has:

```
<arg name="world_name"/>
```

and run the command
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo empty_world_costume.launch world_name:=/opt/ros/1.world
and it didnt work.

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
also edited the original quadrotor_empty_world.launch file by adding the same line :

and used the command :

roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world_.launch world_name:=/opt/ros/1.world
also nothing happened.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:\

> it didnt work

Exactly what happened? Also, the `world_name` argument is the caveat that I was talking about. It's relative to the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. If you echo that you can try putting your world file in that location. Although, I haven't tried this myself.

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
i mean that in both cases the loaded world was the original empty_world and not 1.world at all. regarding the resource path environment, i didnt get any result using 1- `~$  echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`  and 2- ~/catkin_ws$ echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH. the output is empty line . thanks again

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:
See http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
hi @jayess. i managed to get the content of the gazebo_resource_path:
/usr/share/gazebo-7:/usr/share/gazebo_models, however, i dont know the exact echo command for hector_quadrotor_gazebo (you can say i tried different possibilities with no success). how to use that for my case? thanks again

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:\

> i dont know the exact echo command for hector_quadrotor_gazebo

I'm not sure what you're referring to here.

> you can say i tried different possibilities with no success

I don't know how to help if I don't know what you've tried and what the results were.

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
I am sorry if i confused you.iam trying to solve`GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` problem as you mentioned its the reason why costume worlds isnt loading.  i tried
1- echo $HECTOR_QUADROTOR_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE
2-echo $HECTOR_QUADROTOR_WORLD_FILE
3-echo $HECTOR_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE , and none seems correct.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:
I don't know about those env vars. Just the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
oh well, could you please elaborate more on your statement ' One caveat is indicted in the `empty_world.launch` file the `world_name` is with respect to `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` environmental variable' . what else beside adding world_name and excuse me for these question as iam pretty new to ROS,Linux

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:
The explanation is in the link to the tutorial that I posted.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-02**:
@Caesar84 try reading that Gazebo tutorial and if you don't understand something go ahead and ask another question (I believe that this is starting to go off topic). You'll probably find more/better help with this on http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-02**:
thank you for your great help. i did read the tutorial and there isnt much info there. i had followed the same procedure i mentioned earlier and it did work for turtlebot but didnt for hector_quadrotor.